# Shortest path through an array of max-jump-lengths

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am debugging the following problem and posted code as well. Wondering if the code is correct. My current doubt is, whether `i` should always increase (in this line -- `for (;i <= end; i++)`)?

- Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.
- Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.
- Your goal is to reach the last index in the minimum number of jumps.
- For example:
  Given array `A = [2,3,1,1,4]`,
  the minimum number of jumps to reach the last index is 2.
  (Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.)

```
class Solution {
public:
    int jump(vector<int>& nums) {
        int i = 0, n = nums.size(), step = 0, end = 0, maxend = 0;
        while (end < n - 1) {
            step++;
            for (;i <= end; i++) {
                maxend = max(maxend, i + nums[i]);
                if (maxend >= n - 1) return step;
            }
            if(end == maxend) break;
            end = maxend;
        }
        return n == 1 ? 0 : -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: BTW, it is bfs problem not greedy one?

Comment: Consider moving this type of question to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: NO, it is fine. he is asking - what is wrong with his approach not the codereview

Comment: @m69, I am asking whether this line of code is correct, "for (;i <= end; i++)", if not wondering how to find the next point to start with next iteration.

Comment: O(n^2) dp solution exists..you can try now...

Comment: @psyco, thanks for the help, yes, you got my points. :)

Comment: @coderredoc, could you share? Thanks.

Comment: I have an algorithm ready for it should i share it

Comment: @LinMa.:yep ..I will share

Comment: http://www.cnblogs.com/jcliBlogger/p/4649566.html

Comment: @m69, do you think O(n) solution is possible? You can refer to my discussion with coderredoc. :)

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @m69, nice sharing, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dynamic programming Solution Idea: O(n^2)

Suppose the array given is `A[1..n]`. From i-th position you can take a jump of`1 or 2 or 3...A[i]`. You have already calculated the result for all j>=i && j<=n. So now

```
ans[i]=min(ans[i+j],ans[i]) where i+j<=n && j=1,2,...A[i]
```

This way you ca calculate everything.

**O(n^2)** time complexity.

### Modification: O(n)

You can compute it in `O(n)` also. from one position you will always move to a position which will have highest `i+A[i]` values..
I mean suppose you are in `j` th position. Then you will next move to position `j` such that `j+A[j]` is maximum. 
If one of the elements is the last element, jump to the last element. Otherwise, jump to the element with the maximal `j+A[j]`.

**O(n)** solution...

```
Jump     2 3 1 1 4
position 1 2 3 4 5
j+A[j]   3 5 4 5 9
         ^ . . . .
         . ^ . . .    
         . . . . ^  ---> so 2 jumps.. :)
```

---

```
   Jump     2 5 1 1 1 1 1 1
   position 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
   j+A[j]   3 7 4 5 6 7 8 9
            ^ . . . . . . .
            . ^ . . . . . .
            . . . . . . . ^  (Here it is giving 2 jumps)
```

Comment: @LinMa.:check my answer..hope it helps

Comment: @LinMa.: I have posted a O(n) solution..check it...and make sure it is alright..ask me for code if you nedd..

Comment: @coderredoc, I am not sure if always jump highest value helps, suppose we jump to some index where value is 0?

Comment: @LinMa.: Noalways move to something nonzero...the code part must contain a check..for 0 it is a corner case..(except if the last elemnt jump=0)

Comment: @LinMa.: I can remember this same logic getting me a correct answer...just have to add some check for 0 case.

Comment: @coderredoc, nice catch, what is the corner case? Jump to a position where value is not 0 with current max jump capability of current slot? I doubt if it is the most optimized solution, suppose we jump to an area of slow region (not zero region) [1,1,1,1,1,...], while the 2nd largest jump which we miss, could make us jump over this slow region, which has overall faster solutions? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: Oh, no. We can't just jump to the highest possible value. @coderredoc Consider this input: [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]. This algorithm will output "5" while the correct answer is "2".

Comment: @LinMa.: In case of all 1's we will reach it in n-1 jumps...see from pos-1 we can go to only 1 place that is 2..where is the confusion?

Comment: @Yeldar-Kurmangaliyev: 2 3 1 1 1
first check then please comment..here answer is 2. That is what's the case

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev.: Check my algo gives correct answer...!!

Comment: @coderredoc Yeah, I have already understood this :) Just had to read it again. Some code would explanate it better.

Comment: @coderredoc, thanks for all the comments, and confused what do you mean "see from pos-1 we can go to only 1 place"? A bit more details?

Comment: @coderredoc, I think your algorithm for input  [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], will output 5 other than 2. How do you output 2? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa.: I have added the the last input you pointed check it out..you will unerstand..The logic is correct. I am not getting enought time to implement..soon the code will be uploaded.

Comment: @coderredoc, thanks for the update. But I am confused when met with 2, why you jump only 1 element (to 2nd element 5), other than jump 2 element (which is 3rd element 1), I think your algorithm is jump maximum -- jump with the largest index. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92917/discussion-between-coderredoc-and-lin-ma).

Comment: @coderredoc, sorry for the late response. I still do not figure out how your algorithm works for  [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], which could output optimized value 2. If you could show in more details, it will be great.

Comment: For your comments, "I mean suppose you are in j th position. Then you will next move to position j such that j+A[j] is maximum", the first element is 2, j+A[j] = 2+A[0] = 3? So this is why I am confused you jumped to 3rd element, which is 1, other than jump to the 2nd element, which is 5. Please feel free to correct me if my understanding of your algorithm is wrong. :)

Comment: @LinMa.: Initially you will be in 1st position or in cell with jump value 2. Now from there onwards you can jump to 2nd cell (with value=5) or 3rd cell with value=1. Now which one will you chose? Then comes the condition. Initially you will be in cell-1 with value 2.

Comment: @coderredoc, thanks for the response, "Now from there onwards you can jump to 2nd cell (with value=5) or 3rd cell with value=1", I think in this situation, I am not able to choose which one is most optimal value, it is because, if 4rd cell has a super large value, maybe I can jump a small value to 3rd cell, then jump a large value from 4th cell. I think we have to know values afterwards to make a decision. Wondering if you could make a decision whether jump to 2nd cell or 3rd cell? And why? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa.: No you can take the decision..it's easy. You just remember based on what we are taking the decision..it is maximum j+a[j] what does that mean? It means you will reach a point/cell from where you can reach farthest cell. second thing is when in a cell just consider this way..no matter what I can only move to those cells which my currrent cell distance will support. For example if you are in 1 and jump value=2 then you can move to cell 2 or cell 3. Make a jump to the cell with max j+a[j] value ensuring that you willl be able to reach the farthest.

Comment: @coderredoc, know the principle, let us discuss based on an example, for [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], when j is 0, j + A[j] = 0 + 2, you move to 2 (which is A[3], which is 1)? Or when we are at position 0, you check j+A[j] with value j=1 and j=2, which is 6 and 3? I am a bit lost here for j, what do you mean -- current index, or next potential index to jump? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa.: Yes..that's it-- "when we are at position 0, you check j+A[j] with value j=1 and j=2, which is 6 and 3 "...Exactly that we do here...You have understood it well..

Comment: @coderredoc, I take some time today to debug this issue and thanks for the clarification. In your algorithm, for each j, we can jump to range [j, j+A[j]] (both sides of the range are inclusive). One thing I am confused is, the candidate range, saying, j could choose 2,3, or 4, then candidate ranges [2, A[2]], [3, A[3]], [4, A[4]] may not fully overlap. What I mean overlap is, even if 4+A[4] has the maximum value, it does not mean this range could cover all steps which [3, A[3]] or [2, A[2]] could cover. So, I think we missed some opportunities because of go too greedy.

Comment: @coderredoc, but I am not 100% confident and want to listen to your comments why your algorithm could always find optimized jump minimal, and why some steps are safe to skip. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LinMa.: I don't know how can I help? I have added everything in comments and the answer itself..I would like you to dry run the algo over an example array.

Comment: @coderredoc, debugged your solution for some time today and agree your solution is correct. One more thing which I am not clear is, what is the logical meaning of max j+A[j]? And why using it will always have the desired max jump value? If you could share some of your great thoughts behind the scene, it will be great. Thanks. :)

Comment: @LinMa.: Suppose you are now in position i then you will consider all the jumps j of 1..i such that the it will give me a chance to reach the farthest.that's what j+A[j]recisely gives...

Comment: @coderredoc, that is correct. But how do you prove we do not miss any opportunities other j+A[j] provides -- when j is not the one giving maximum j+A[j]. I worked on a few samples, and your algorithm is always correct, and I want to see if we could prove it, so that we can guarantee the algorithm is correct. :)

Comment: @coderredoc, thanks for all the help. Mark as answered. Have a good weekend. :)

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways of solution here.

### Recursion. Easy, but inefficient

You simply need to start from your index 0, and for every index `i` try to jump to 1 to `a[i]` indices ahead, while holding the best result for the last index. It has a high algorithm complexity, so that should be choosen only if efficiency is really irrelevant or `n` is pretty small.

Algorithm will look like this:

```
int best = 2147483647;
vector<int> A;

void Jump(int index, int step)
{
    if (step > best)
    {
        // for positive values, if step > best we won't improve our result
        // avoid worthless calculations
        return; 
    }
    if (index == A.size() - 1)
    {
        if (step < best) best = step;
        return;
    }

    int maxJumps = A[index];
    for (int i = index; i <= min(index + maxJumps, A.size() - 1); i++) 
    {
        Jump(i, step + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // read input
    Jump(0, 0);
}
```

For your case, the recursion will go this way:

```
Start from A[0] (equal to 2)                             step = 0
> A[0+1] with step+1 (equal to 3)                        step = 1
>> A[1+1] with step+1 (equal to 1)                       step = 2
>>> A[2+1] with step+1 (equal to 1)                      step = 3
>>>> A[3+1] with step+1 (equal to 4)                     step = 4
>>>>> End of array. Compare step(4), best (MAXINT)         best = 4
>> A[1+2] with step+1 (equal to 1)                       step = 2
>>>> A[3+1] with step+1 (equal to 4)                      step = 3
>>>>> End of array. Compare step (3), best (4)             best = 3
>> A[1+3] with step+1 (equal to 4)                       step = 2
>>>>> End of array. Compare step(2), best (3)              best = 2
> A[0+2] with step+1 (equal to 1)                        step = 2
>>> A[2+1] with step+1 (equal to 1)                       step = 3
>>>> A[3+1] with step+1 (equal to 4)                      step = 4
>>>>> End of array. Compare step(4), best(2)               best = 2
```

**Dynamic. Smart and efficient**

This approach uses [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Let we have an array `B` of the same length as array A. Let `B[i]` mean "how many steps does it take at **minimum** to jump to A[i]". If we know `B[i]`, then we can say that we can jump to all possible indices (from `i + 1` to `i + A[i]`) for `B[i] + 1`. So, all you need is to walk through the array from 0 to N-1 and look ahead, **improving** the result for every `i` to `i + a[i]`.

Something like this:

```
vector<int> A, B;
int n;

int main() 
{
    // read n; read A of size n
    B.reserve(n); // B should be the same size and initialized with zeroes (by default)

    B[0] = 0; // not obligatory, 0 by default, just for clearness
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= min(i + A[i], n - 1); j++)
        {
            // improve result if we weren't there yet or if we can come to A[j]
            // faster if we go from A[i]
            if (B[j] == 0 || B[i] + 1 < B[j]) 
                B[j] = B[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm will work this way:

```
A = 2 3 1 1 4
B = 0 0 0 0 0

i = 0, improve 0+1, 0+2
B = 0 1 1 0 0

i = 1, improve 1+1, 1+2, 1+3
B = 0 1 2 2 2

i = 2, no improvements 
i = 3, no improvements
```

The answer is stored in `B[n - 1]`.
I have implemented a [working IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/Cw7aIU).

Comment: @LinMa Oh, just a typo.

Comment: Hi Yeldar, studied your code and it seems your code of internal j-loop even does not touch A[j] = 0 node, correct? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa It does :) Here: `j <= min(j + A[i], A.size() - 1)`. We update the value for next `A[i]` indices.

Comment: Thanks Yeldar, I think then A[i] is 0, the condition of loop is false, you never execute the loop, "(int j = i + 1; j <= min(i + A[i], n - 1); j++)", correct? Since j initialize to be i+1, which cannot be j <= min(i + A[i], n - 1). Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. ;)

Comment: @LinMa Yes, if `a[i] == 0`, then the loop will skip this index, because we cannot improve the results from this position. The inner loop will not work, and `i` will continue calculating. Open IDEOne demo and try to input something like `3 1 1 1 0 1`, it will output "0", i.e. not reachable.

Comment: Thanks Yeldar, do you think always jump maximum will find the optimal results? I am confused how jump maximum approach works for input, " [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]."? I think your approach could always find the most optimal results. If my understanding is wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing the algorithm. Now, do **BFS** described as follows:

```
int A[N];         // It contains the initial values
int result[N];    // Initialise all with positive infinty or INT_MAX in C
bool visited[N];  // Initially, all initialise with '0' means none of the index is visited
queue Q;          // create a queue 

index = 1
cost = 0
push index in rear of Q.
result[index] = cost
visited[index] = true

while(Q is not empty) {
    index = pop the value from the front of the Q.
    cost = cost + 1

    for(i in 1 to A[index]) {
        temp_index = index + i;
        if(temp_index <= N   AND  visited[temp_index] == false) {
            push temp_index in rear of Q.
            result[temp_index] = cost
            visited[temp_index] = true
        }
    }
}

// Finally print the value of result[N]
print result[N]
```

**Note:** There also exist a **DP** Approach whose time-complexity is **O(n**<sup>**2**</sup>**)**.

Comment: I guess both are of same complexity

Comment: Hi psyco, your array result and visited starts with index 1 other than zero, and why? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, psyco, I think you should output result[N], other than A[N]?

Comment: @LinMa I started with index 1 instead of zero . Reason : **Just like that**. I could have started it with `0` but later i felt like starting with `1` itself. And, nice observation, it means you have read it properly. thanks man thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: Thanks psyco, another issue I found is, it seems you always assign value of cost, I mean this line "result[temp_index] = cost". I think you should only assign if lower? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa No dear. if you look closely. Once any index is traversed, then its corresponding `visited[temp_index]` is marked as true with lowest cost,and it will not be traversed again.

Comment: Thanks psyco, wondering if DP is faster or BFS is faster? Even if they are of the same time complexity? Have a good weekend.